# Can anyone explain what this string means?

Tags: encoding, url-encoding

Can anyone help me explain what this string means?

```
KeyWord=%EC%E5%EB%E8%F1%F1%E0
```

I want to understand what is this? Is it hexadecimal or this string is encrypted by some keys?

Comment: This is [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) typically used in urls. It just a sequence of hex encoded bytes with no encryption involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [percent-encoded string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

The decoded version of the string is `ìåëèññà`.

Each character of the string has a percent-encoded representation, so the first character `ì` is encoded to `%EC`, and so on.

The percent-encoding of a string can be different depending on the character set of the string. In this case, the string is in ISO-8859-1, where `ì` is represented as `0xEC`, hence the percent-encoding `%EC`. However, in UTF-8 it is represented as `0xC3 0xAC`, so the percent-encoded version of the UTF-8 string would start with `%C3%AC`.